# Facing error when importing downlodable product in magento2

Tags: magento2, importexport, downloadable

I want to import downloadble product 
when i was importing catalog_product.csv it's giving me below error:

> 1. Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 1
> 2. Error move file in row(s): 1
>      General system exception happened
>      Additional data:
>      SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'website_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `downloadable_link_price` (`price_id`,`link_id`,`website_id`,`price`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price_id` = VALUES(`price_id`), `link_id` = VALUES(`link_id`), `website_id` = VALUES(`website_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`)

Comment: Do you use website id columns in csv?

Comment: No, it's set in code default  Like
dlp.website_id=' . self::DEFAULT_WEBSITE_ID,

Comment: Check below link May be it will help you :https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2666

Comment: There  are not reference for downloadable product

Comment: Yes not for specific for downlodable product, but its regarding product import issue as same as yours. 

Are you able to import simple product using csv?

Comment: Yes , i can successfully  imported simple product@shail

Comment: Did you check this URL:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109135/import-export-error-magento-2-0-1

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152428/magento2-import-product-with-images-using-absolute-path

Answer (score 0):

```
/*if (count($dataLink['price'])) {
        $this->connection->insertOnDuplicate(
            $this->_resource->getTableName('downloadable_link_price'),
            $this->downloadableHelper->prepareDataForSave($this->dataLinkPrice, $dataLink['price'])
        );
    }*/
```

Commenting above code from Magento\DownloadableImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Type\Downloadable.php
Fixes myissue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the method fillDataTitleLink(array $options) in vendor/magento/module-downloadable-import-export/Import/Product/Type/Downloadable.php.

It does a select query from the downloadable_link table, with a left join on the downloadable_link_price table, on link_id and website_id.

However, since the row has not yet been inserted into the downloadable_link table, the result of the query fills link_id and website_id as NULL.

Then, when setting the var $existOption, it calls fillExistOptions($this->dataLinkPrice, $option, $existingOptions).

(fillExistOptions: https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation//class_magento_1_1_downloadable_import_export_1_1_helper_1_1_data.html)

fillExistOptions sets the result using array_replace($base, $option, $existingOption). This replaces link_id and website_id with NULL, which ultimately causes the error. It returns $result['price'] with the null values, which is then used in saveLinkOptions() as $dataLink['price'] in insertOnDuplicate(...).

fillDataTitleLink() is called in saveLinkOptions() BEFORE the latter method inserts the row into the downloadable_link_price table.

The only solution I have found so far, and it has been working for me, is to add this in fillDataTitleLink, after $existingOptions is set with the select query:

```
foreach($existingOptions as $k=>$v):
  if($k['website_id'] == NULL):
    $existingOptions[$k]['website_id'] = self::DEFAULT_WEBSITE_ID;
  endif;
endforeach;
```

Still investigating if there's a better way to solve it.